# Service messaging is not available

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to integrate FCM with nextjs project.
This error is occurring whenever I save the firebase.js config file. I'm not being able to use Firebase Cloud Messaging in Firebase V9.

```
I use firebase 9.10.0
```

[image]

**my firebase.js config**

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getToken, getMessaging, onMessage } from 'firebase/messaging';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "*************",
  authDomain: "********************",
  projectId: "******************",
  storageBucket: "*****************",
  messagingSenderId: "*************",
  appId: "**********************"
};

console.log('*** Environment ***', process.env.REACT_APP_ENV)
console.log('*** Firebase Config ***', firebaseConfig)

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp);

export const getOrRegisterServiceWorker = () => {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    return window.navigator.serviceWorker
      .getRegistration('/firebase-push-notification-scope')
      .then((serviceWorker) => {
        if (serviceWorker) return serviceWorker;
        return window.navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js', {
          scope: '/firebase-push-notification-scope',
        });
      });
  }
  throw new Error('The browser doesn`t support service worker.');
};

export const getFirebaseToken = () =>
  getOrRegisterServiceWorker()
    .then((serviceWorkerRegistration) =>
      getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: "***********", serviceWorkerRegistration }));

export const onForegroundMessage = () =>
  new Promise((resolve) => onMessage(messaging, (payload) => resolve(payload)));
```

Comment: Have you tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73554200/20447561) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75134189/20447561)?

Comment: I try both of them but  not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ather searing a lot I found solutions:

I change the code of my `firebase.js` file to the below code

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging, getToken } from "firebase/messaging";
import localforage from "localforage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "**********************",
  authDomain: "*******************",
  projectId: "******************",
  storageBucket: "****************",
  messagingSenderId: "****************",
  appId: "**************"
};
// Initialize Firebase

const firebaseCloudMessaging = {
  init: async () => {
     initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    try {
      const messaging = getMessaging();
      const tokenInLocalForage = await localStorage.getItem("fcm_token");

      // Return the token if it is alredy in our local storage
      if (tokenInLocalForage !== null) {
        return tokenInLocalForage;
      }

      // Request the push notification permission from browser
      const status = await Notification.requestPermission();
      if (status && status === "granted") {
        // Get new token from Firebase
        const fcm_token = await getToken(messaging, {
          vapidKey:
            "********************",
        });
        console.log("token in fcm_token", fcm_token);
        // Set token in our local storage
        if (fcm_token) {
          localforage.setItem("fcm_token", fcm_token);
          return fcm_token;
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return null;
    }
  },
};
export { firebaseCloudMessaging };
```